# Uninstalling Plugin in Vim

Tags: vim, uninstallation

After installing many plugins in my ~/.vim folder, I feel I no more understand the contents of that folder and I don't feel enough confidence about deleting the plugin from ~/.vim/plugin to uninstall a plugin. What if there are related files in other directories? What if the documentation was already registered (:helptags), yet the plugin will be removed? Is there any procedure to uninstall vim-plugins? I don't really want my Vim to end up being as messy as my Windows.

Comment: To avoid the problem in the first place you should use tpope's pathogen (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332). It separates all plugins by keeping each plugin in a separate subdirectory. It makes removing a plugin really easy...

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be a very good plugin, but it is too late. Anyway, why not post it as an answer for people to benefit?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to uninstall a plugin which was installed into ~/.vim manually, you should redownload its archive, list its content and manually remove everything, then run `:helptags` again (this will remove missing tags). If plugin was installed from a vimball, see documentation for `:RmVimball`. Vimball archives normally have `.vba` or `.vba.gz` extensions. In case you don't remember vimball file name, it is contained into `~/.vim/.VimballRecord` file.

In order to avoid this problem in the future, try [vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905) plugin. Like pathogen, it puts each plugin into separate directory, but is also capable of downloading, installing and updating them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe this is the best possible answer. I will try vim-addon-manager. I started to believe that Vim should have a market similar to that of iPhone and Android. This way, it gives the users the change to search the market to see if there are any interesting blogs. Or may be there is already a plugin for such a thing? Any idea?

Comment: @Promather. In order to have market, vim must have a VM so that it is won't be so easy to get source code. Maybe somebody will adjust vim-addon-manager so that it will be capable of browsing vim.org, but there definitely won't be any market in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 13):

To manage easily plugins in vim use [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332)
and this awesome article --> [come home to vim](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/)

Comment: Pathogen is nice... But Vundle is way better to manage and update plugins: https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim

Answer (score 12):

If you install vim plugin via Vundle, it's easy to uninstall plugin, comment out the plugin in .vimrc, example:

```
"Bundle 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
```

then

```
:BundleClean
```

common commands of Vundle:
:BundleList              -List all plugins
:BundleInstall          -Install all plugins
:BundleInstall!         -Update all plugins
:BundleSearch foo   -Find foo plugin
:BundleSearch! foo  -refresh buffer for foo plugin
:BundleClean           -clean all plugins if the plugin not defined in .vimrc

Answer (score 5):

You can simply run:

```sh
vim +PlugClean
```

OR open vim and run `:PlugClean`.

On running this command, it will ask you to remove the plugin directories. answer with `y` and it will clean the plugs.

Comment: This is not true for me. Mine only attempts to uninstall "Invalid Plugins". I'm using VimPlug, on MacOSX Mohave with Vim8.2

Comment: This worked form me, but first I had to comment in the `.vimrc` file the plugins to be uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, even the much downloaded [Pathogen.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) documentation **boldly** suggests (their emphasis, not mine):

> **For new users, I recommend using Vim's built-in package management instead.** `:help packages`

---

Ok, I can take a hint, that pathogen is not for most of us new users.

So then looking into native vim packages, and what it has to offer...

The skinny from **`:help packages`** seems to be this:

> ... A package can be downloaded as an archive and unpacked in its own directory.
>
> Thus the files are not mixed with files of other plugins.
>
> That makes it easy to update and remove.